# Element is not in source code at runtime

Tags: jquery, html

On the click handler of a button I want to add a hidden element inside a div :

```
...
<div id="produits_choisis"></div>
...
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#btnOne').click(function() { // btnOne is a HTML button
        $('#produits_choisis').append("<input type='hidden' id='produit_x' />");
    });
...
});
```

When I click the button then I look the page's source code , but the div produits_choisis is still empty ! So why is it empty ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JavaScript operates on the in-memory DOM, not the original source code to the page.

Use a DOM inspector to see a representation of the modified DOM.

Comment: "a DOM inspector", like right-click -> inspect element and the DOM inspector that shows up when you press F12.

Comment: Ok I made right-click->inspect element , and I saw the hidden element in the source code ! thank you very much !